# Strange Icon Behavior in Android Studio / Flutter

Tags: flutter, android-studio, dart, intellij-idea, bug-reporting

I've noticed a strange behavior in Flutter projects within Android Studio (2020.3.1 Patch 3) on Monterey Mac.

It may apply to more cases than that, I don't know.

Anyway, if inside a dart file, you type

`Icons.`

["icons dot"]

The auto-complete behavior seems to go into some kind of infinite loop/algorithm gone wrong:

[image]

It starts filling in all your icon options, but it does so slowly (as if downloading from the internet on a slow connection), in a nonsensical order (notice the lack of alphabetical order in the screenshot), and basically takes forever as far as I can tell.  It makes it impossible to find/choose an Icon.

It does this the same way even if you are offline.

If you delete the dot and re-type it, the whole process starts from the beginning.

If you don't type the dot, you get an instant list of available Icons (as normal without the graphics), but the list is incomplete, truncating even before Icons beginning with B are reached.

It sure seems like a bug, but I'm not sure... and even if it was a bug I don't know where to report it: Android Studio, the Flutter plugin, the Dart plugin, or IntilliJ.

Does anyone have an explanation (answer), or can at least verify the behavior (comment only please)?

Comment: Seems to be caused by this bug: https://github.com/flutter/flutter-intellij/issues/5850

Comment: Can confirme the behavior too, on both IntelliJ and Android Studio. The issue above is for custom icon packages, but in this case you are referring to the standard material Icons.

Comment: Thanks! Where should I send the bug report?